# Postfix not actually sending e-mails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, troubleshooting

So after following the Ubuntu Postfix tutorial, I tried their recommended test

```
telnet localhost 25
MAIL FROM: person@mydomain.com
RCTP TO: person@gmail.com
DATA
some text here
.
```

I received a successful 250 OK Queued as C55230429543

However, when I checked my gmail account (including spam folders) there was no e-mail there.

Any ideas where I can check to see where things went wrong?

```
Aug 25 22:34:06 mydomain postfix/cleanup[16130]: 23C20508CA: message-id=<20100825223401.23C20508CA@server1.mydomain.com>
Aug 25 22:34:06 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15822]: 23C20508CA: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=372, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 25 22:34:12 mydomain postfix/smtp[16131]: fatal: specify a password table via the `smtp_sasl_password_maps' configuration parameter
Aug 25 22:34:13 mydomain postfix/master[15819]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtp pid 16131 exit status 1
Aug 25 22:34:13 mydomain postfix/master[15819]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
Aug 25 22:34:35 mydomain postfix/smtpd[16127]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.
```

I changed my actual domain to 'mydomain'

Comment: please provide a snippet of /var/log/mail.log and the result of mailq

Comment: added a snippet of the mail.log... Where can I find the result of mailq?

Answer (score 7):

A little search on Google for `fatal: specify a password table via the smtp_sasl_password_maps` would lead you to [this page](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?s=04ca19dd8233e7c65d8e83725e17ec95&t=5959&page=3). On page 3, you will find that:

```
Apr 14 18:03:08 flamingweasel postfix/smtp[17932]: fatal: specify a password table via the `smtp_sasl_password_maps' configuration parameter
```

is due to a typo in your configuration that goes undetected. The line you have is:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

Where you want it to be:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

And if you don't have this line, you're probably missing it.

Comment: Unbelievably the man page has it incorrect too. You, Sir, are correct.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you start by reading the message and acting on it.  Especially the bit where it says:

```
fatal: specify a password table via the `smtp_sasl_password_maps' configuration parameter`.
```

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer it never mentioned anything about password maps.  I'm new to this, where does the password table live?

Comment: Well, evidently you configured sasl without knowing it.  You either need to finish configuring it, or disable it.

Comment: I configured SASL based on the guide above... I configured it exactly how it states in the guide

Comment: Obviously not exactly, or it would be working, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ThinkingInBits Countless guides don't work out-of-the-box and need to be adapted.